# how to import module in file in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

so im making a game and made a folder called scripts and inside it i have multiple .py files here is the structure

```
 scripts
>   arrow.py
>   sword.py
>   player.py
>   enemy.py
>   variables.py
>   functions.py
>   tileset.py
>   camera.py
>   coin.py
>   vfx.py
>   save.py

main.py
```

now the question is how can i import variables.py in enemy.py {using python 3.7}

i tried all of the following none worked:

'''

```
import .variables [in the enemy file]
from . import variables [in the enemy file]
from .scripts import variables [in the enemy file]
import .scripts.variables as variables [in the enemy file]
```

'''

all gave me an error

Comment: import `from script import variables` in enemey.py file

Comment: gives an error: No module named scripts

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try like this and see if it works

```
from scripts import enemy
```

Comment: i think u dis understood me because i wanted to import the variables in the enemy not the enemy in the main but thank u anyways

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following code in *variables.py*:

```
VAR = "VALUE"
```

In *enemy.py* file you should do:

```
import variables
print(variables.VAR)
```

or

```
from variables import VAR
print(VAR)
```

If you want to use *variables.py* in *main.py*:

```
import scripts.variables
print(scripts.variables.VAR)
```

or

```
from scripts.variables import VAR
print(VAR)
```

Comment: it works when i run the code enemy.py but when i run the main.py which calls a function in it it crashes and tell me no module name 'variables'

Comment: then your folder/file structure is not what you posted.

Comment: it is, if you want i can send you a screenshot

Answer (score -1):

So I tried everything and found out that if you have the same problem (you get an error if you run the main.py but wont get the error running the enemy.py) you will need to do

```
import scripts.variables
```

so it should be relative to the main.py not the enemy.py

Comment: that is what I wrote in my answer. read again. and mark as correct.

Comment: what you said is use "import variables" in "enemy.py" which gives an error

Comment: You must review what you write, before send. As you said “it works when I run the code enemy.py [...]”.